# Matplotlib, can't plot graph with different dimensions in real time

Tags: python, matplotlib

Good day,

So I was looking to plot some real time data via matplotlib. The only example I managed to find online looked like this:

```
x = np.linspace(0, maxLen, maxLen)
y = np.linspace((maxLen/-2), (maxLen/2), maxLen)
plt.ion()
plt.ylim([0,50])
plt.xlim([0,maxLen])
self.fig = plt.figure()
ax = self.fig.add_subplot(maxLen-1)
self.line1, = ax.plot(x, y, 'r-')

# In Loop with self.ay updating with new dataset
self.line1.set_ydata(self.ay)
#self.line1.set_xdata(self.ax)
self.fig.canvas.draw()
```

This works, but the problem is, this ax.plot function seems to require that the length of x and y have to be the same dimension! Is there any way I can go around this rule?

Also, My graph looks squashed. Is there any way I can increase the width of it?

[image]

Comment: Of course `x` and `y` should be the same dimension. How else will you plot a set of numbers versus another set of numbers?

Comment: Your squashed graph comes from this `fig.add_subplot(maxLen-1)`. Why `maxLen-1` subplots? Just `fig.add_subplot(111)` is enough for a single figure.

Comment: expanding on what @Evert said, one option you have is to fill `x` and `y` with masked values in a numpy masked array to make them the same length.

Comment: ah looks like i have to fill it up myself with 0's. I thought matplotlib fills it for you